# Forward Rate Volatility Calculation - Caps for Libor Market Model

Tags: interest

I am trying to calculate the forward rate volatilities from cap volatilities using Rebonato`s volatility model. Unfortunately, my approach always results in unrealistic forward rate vols. Furthermore, as I just have ATM Cap prices/vols, I cannot use the standard quantlib CapFloorVolTermSurface to construct my forward rate vols.
Does anyone have a method, source, example in Python etc. for such a calculation?

This is the code I am using with some example data:

```
# Libraries
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from scipy.stats import norm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



# Input Parameters
cap_prices = [0.0, 0.0, 0.020011950921853195, 0.05074873822182878, 0.10336895891346086, 0.16588313145875605, 0.2533724574981232, 0.35174757325406103, 0.4701444936626773, 0.593081492686773, 0.7359526708319613, 0.877989696611585, 1.0260351088701913, 1.1600196162729612, 1.3184578716861968, 1.4829447531664126, 1.6496328932866386, 1.8065491133537495, 1.9820594340975828, 2.1490003466838026, 2.3225239850625234, 2.4917656955667002, 2.667050398665095, 2.8382619196071355, 3.0177156787135777, 3.189359811385567, 3.3707654678881247, 3.547975494866014, 3.730623411067357, 3.9023650797890843, 4.084721082037504, 4.261963691806112, 4.443314057979344, 4.613105915636499, 4.79282889899193, 4.967174224337874, 5.149200089709508, 5.310646042082241, 5.485811919729442, 5.659558511569442, 5.829614241194288, 5.994257618540332, 6.161495290757493, 6.323429110131764, 6.49006121048868, 6.647293059843137, 6.809224902486905, 6.96847370063799, 7.130463504868825, 7.281679545808297]
strikes = [0.004849792451814713, 0.005451685952049794, 0.0062512100930573805, 0.007193498719152967, 0.008261355914459145, 0.009416334324326169, 0.01055839873497409, 0.011689476404909173, 0.012754826632794203, 0.013766707730532313, 0.014703677769218961, 0.015590397988913039, 0.016469739452814425, 0.017311301978518785, 0.01804840121058648, 0.018723144744248053, 0.019403277949767234, 0.020055902491381006, 0.02061959943212093, 0.02115007947765411, 0.021641086946377633, 0.022081554325116624, 0.022475002908413484, 0.02285795251641165, 0.023222384445077595, 0.02355677277644328, 0.023849985574081144, 0.02409123389565899, 0.02427960601198556, 0.024453183806526894, 0.02461667740009192, 0.024769546952392436, 0.024911271573602314, 0.025041347690598202, 0.02515928730300895, 0.02526461610929479, 0.025356871485923523, 0.025435600304625477, 0.025501423796050745, 0.025562734092897478, 0.02562097641569784, 0.025675619242567206, 0.025726142034109705, 0.02577203490840359, 0.025812798169585514, 0.025847941687937193, 0.025876984128795716, 0.025899452027030454, 0.02591511856031686, 0.025928016839032297]
discount_factors = [0.99806973, 0.99565537, 0.99264992, 0.98876458, 0.98382339, 0.97767011, 0.97025005, 0.9617984, 0.95234658, 0.94217088, 0.9313256, 0.92001912, 0.90823235, 0.89578857, 0.88292001, 0.8701645, 0.85735653, 0.84405628, 0.83054739, 0.81741161, 0.80425875, 0.79119816, 0.77839357, 0.76587289, 0.75330698, 0.74080304, 0.72851779, 0.71661701, 0.70527458, 0.69455344, 0.68402033, 0.67362934, 0.66339853, 0.65334579, 0.64348887, 0.63384532, 0.62443248, 0.61526749, 0.6063673, 0.59773212, 0.58923836, 0.5808657, 0.57262467, 0.56452597, 0.55658046, 0.54879915, 0.54119311, 0.53377354, 0.52655172, 0.51953459, 0.51265042]
T = np.arange(0.5, 25.5, 0.5)

# Code for optimization

# Bacheliermodel for normal vol
def bachelier_caplet_price(F, K, sigma, T, df):
    d1 = (F - K) / (sigma * np.sqrt(T))
    caplet_price = df * ((F-K) * norm.cdf(d1) + sigma * np.sqrt(T) * norm.pdf(d1))
    return caplet_price

# Rebonato formula
def rebonato_volatility(T, alpha, beta, gamma, delta):
    return (alpha + beta * T) * np.exp(-gamma * T) + delta

# Objective Function
def objective_function(params, cap_prices, forward_swap_rates, discount_factors, T):
    alpha, beta, gamma, delta = params
    sigma = rebonato_volatility(T, alpha, beta, gamma, delta)
    model_prices = np.array([
        bachelier_caplet_price(forward_swap_rates[i], forward_swap_rates[i], T[i], sigma[i], discount_factors[i])
        for i in range(len(forward_swap_rates))
    ])
    return np.sum((model_prices - cap_prices) ** 2)

# Optimizer
initial_params = [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]
result = minimize(objective_function, initial_params, args=(cap_prices, strikes, discount_factors, T), method='SLSQP')
optimized_params = result.x
alpha, beta, gamma, delta = optimized_params

# Calculation of forward rate vols
forward_rate_vols = np.array([rebonato_volatility(t, alpha, beta, gamma, delta) for t in T])
```

The results I get are obviously wrong, as they should be closer to the implied cap vols and not just increasing.[image]

The implied cap vols look like this:

```
implied_cap_vols = {'1': 0.20199999999999999, '2': 0.366, '3': 0.496, '4': 0.609, '5': 0.693, '6': 0.7509999999999999, '7': 0.7709999999999999, '8': 0.7909999999999999, '9': 0.802, '10': 0.807, '12': 0.8059999999999999, '15': 0.794, '20': 0.7609999999999999, '25': 0.723}
```

Thank you very much for any help on this!

Comment: No, in this example, quantlib is used to generate a vol surface with different strikes. I just have data for ATM caps and therefore cannot use this approach. Do you know another way of doing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. I used the following parametric volatility structure instead of Rebonato`s structure and got quiet good results on it

[image]
[image]

```
def estimated_volatility(T, alpha, beta, gamma, delta):
    def integrand(t):
        volatility = np.abs((alpha * (T-t) + delta) * np.exp(-beta * (T-t)) + gamma)
        return volatility ** 2
    integral_result, _ = quad(integrand, 0, T)
    return np.sqrt(1/T * integral_result)
```